# Using a type alias in a linq statement is generating an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

For some reason this statement is working fine:

```
vms.Where(vm => vm.MessageType == ValidationMessage.EnumValidationMessageType.Warning)
```

But if at the top of the class, I define an alias (to save space):

```
using MsgType = ValidationMessage.EnumValidationMessageType;
```

Then the resulting line of code:

```
vms.Where(vm => vm.MessageType == MsgType.Warning)
```

Gives me an error:

[image]
"Delegate '`System.Func<ValidationMessage, int, bool>`' does not take 1 arguments". What's odd about that is that isn't the Delegate I'm using. I'm using the '`System.Func<ValidationMessage, bool>`' overload of `.Where<>()` - same as when I wasn't using the alias.

Note that everywhere else the alias is being used works fine, it's only inside these linq delegates that it breaks. Why is this happening?

Comment: Ahahaha. If I try to work around it by giving it an arg for the second (index) argument: `vms.Where((vm,i) => vm.MessageType == MsgType.Warning)`, it then flips back and says "Delegate 'System.Func<ValidationMessage, bool>' does not take 2 arguments"! What a joke.

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you try to compile? Or just the VS error detection shows them?

Comment: Really good point. My code wasn't otherwise in a compile state so I didn't try it, but I commented out the unfinished code and tried running and much more reasonable error: it couldn't find the namespace for my type alias declaration. The solution was to fully spell out the path to the type: `using MsgType = WPF.Utilities.ObjectModel.ValidationMessage.EnumValidationMessageType;` After that everything fixed itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon trying to run my program, all those errors cleared away and a single error appeared complaining about my type alias declaration.

The problem was that the `ValidationMessage.EnumValidationMessageType` type existed within a namespace, which had been declared further up:

```
using WPF.Utilities.ObjectModel;
using MsgType = ValidationMessage.EnumValidationMessageType;
```

Of course, C# can't figure out where the type comes from based on prior namespace inclusions, I had to spell it out fully:

```
using WPF.Utilities.ObjectModel;
using MsgType = WPF.Utilities.ObjectModel.ValidationMessage.EnumValidationMessageType;
```

Once I did that, the other problem went away.

I guess I was just so caught up and confounded by the weird errors coming out of the linq statement, combined by the fact that VS didn't show any errors where I was using the alias in the ternary operators above, that I didn't see the obvious error there.

Thanks for the hint nemesv - I should know better than to trust the design-time compiler.